# SQLAlchemy-migrate on a new Table with a relationship?

Tags: foreign-keys, sqlalchemy, database-migration

Let's say I have created this new SQLAlchemy class:

```
class C(Base):
    id = Column(Int, primary_key=True)
    tags = relationship("B")
```

I want to create this table for SQLAlchemy-migrate.
However, I don't know how to convert 'relationship' from the declarative style, or what schema `tags` should have.

How do I write code for SQLAlchemy-migrate that will create or drop this Table?

Comment: Have you tried ?
http://sqlalchemy-migrate.readthedocs.org/en/v0.7.1/changeset.html

Comment: Sadly, but docs have no answer for this question